# Starting a container that was already started and stoppped

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker, selenium-grid

I started a container using

```
docker run -d --link hub:hub --name chromeNode selenium/node-chrome
```

Now if I run the same command I know it will throw me an error as below

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "/chromeNode" is 
already in use by container f05717d38a676946be74300768dd3d2cb9dd6733d88e1c1e46d85cef3de18c06. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name..
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So if I have to start the same container `chromeNode` if I just do

`docker start chromeNode` will it automatically link to the `hub` since I am not using `--link` argument?

Or should I destroy the container and `run` a new one each and every time?

Comment: docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" chromeNode
and see if it is still linked after restarting container

Comment: No it's not linked

Comment: I apologize. It's still linked. This is a very useful command to find that out. Thanks a lot for that. I think this should be the answer

Comment: np. i've added the answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once created, containers will remain linked after they are restarted. To make sure they are linked run this command after restarting container:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" chromeNode
```

Answer (score -1):

docker `run` command **creates** container from image, **configures** it (expose ports, volumes) and **starts** container.

`docker run` command **only starts** already created container. `docker stop` command is shutting down the container, but don`t destroy them.

if you need to have 2 the same containers then you need to execute command 2 times with different container names.

```
docker run -d --link hub:hub --name chromeNode_1 selenium/node-chrome
docker run -d --link hub:hub --name chromeNode_2 selenium/node-chrome
```

Comment: Well, I know that. But I will be running the `docker run` command programatically. In that case I won't be able to know  if I already have a container called `chromeNode_1` or `chromeNode_2`. So in that case the solution would be to destroy the existing one and recreate another one with same name?